# React Synthetic Event distinguish Left and Right click events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am trying to distinguish between left and right clicks in an `onClick` function:

```
const App = () => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    // detect a left click
    if (e.which == 1){ 
      // do something
    }
  };
  return <p onClick={handleClick}>Something</p>;
};
```

Turns out `e.which` is undefined for [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). How can I distinguish between left and right clicks here?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In modern versions of React (v16+), both `onClick` and `onContextMenu` props need to be passed to detect both left- and right-click events:

```
return <p onClick={handleClick} onContextMenu={handleClick}>Something</p>
```

You can either check against `e.nativeEvent.button` (as the other answer implies), or check `e.type` on the synthetic event itself.

Using `e.type`

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if (e.type === 'click') {
    console.log('Left click');
  } else if (e.type === 'contextmenu') {
    console.log('Right click');
  }
};
```

Using `e.nativeEvent`

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if (e.nativeEvent.button === 0) {
    console.log('Left click');
  } else if (e.nativeEvent.button === 2) {
    console.log('Right click');
  }
};
```

Here's an [updated demo](https://codepen.io/matthemattics/pen/VwymOLR?editors=1011) demonstrating how this works.

You may also want to read the [React documentation for SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events).

*[(original demo)](http://jsbin.com/seyeliv/edit?html,output)*

Comment: e.type's value is "click" for both left AND middle-scroll click. =\ (upvoted, went crazy looking for this answer)

Comment: Note: for onMouseDown it's e.button === 0

Answer (score 25):

The property you're looking for is `e.button` or `e.buttons`.

> The button number that was pressed when the mouse event was fired: Left button=0, middle button=1 (if present), right button=2.
>    <sub>– [MDN:Web/Events/click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)</sub>

However, with or without react, I'm only getting click events with the left mouse button (trackpad). You could use onMouseDown which works for me.

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/nuhavu/1/edit?js,output) using `e.buttons`. You may want to preventDefault in onContextMenu also.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
if (e.button === 0) { // or e.nativeEvent.which === 1
    // do something on left click
}
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/4vdLj8k2/1/)

Answer (score 6):

```
onContextMenu={e => console.log("right-click")}


onClick={e => console.log("left-click")}
```

I found this solution on [React's official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) in the "Mouse Events" section.

Here's the [TypeScript definition](https://felixgerschau.com/react-typescript-oncontextmenu-event-type/) of onContextMenu's synthetic event.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The approach that I use to distinguish between left and right click:

```
const buttons = {
  left: 0,
  middle: 1,
  right: 2,
};

export const App = () => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.button === buttons.left) {
      console.log('left');
    } else if (e.button === buttons.middle) {
      console.log('middle');
    } else if (e.button === buttons.right) {
      console.log('right');
    }
 };

 return (
    <div onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()} onMouseDown={handleChange}>
      Click me!
    </div>
 );
};
```